# Error shown in initialization of array in mips

Tags: arrays, syntax-error, mips32, qtspim

The code is:

```
# first Spim program

  .data                 #Global Data here

N: .word 5  #loop count
X: .word 2,4,6,8,10 #array of integers
SUM: .word 0    #location of final sum
str : .asciiz "The sum of the array is ="

  .text
  .globl main   #main defined globally

main: 
  lw $s0, N       #Loop count N(initially must be zero) loaded in $s0
  la $t0,X      #Address of X into t0
  $s1, $s1, $zero   #logical and with zero results in zero

loop:
  lw $t1, 0(#t0)
  add $s1,$s1,$t1
  addi $t0, $t0, $4
  addi $s0, $s0, -1
  bne $0, $s0, loop

  sw $s1, SUM

  li $v0, 10
  syscall 

  .end
```

## The error is

Exception occurred at PC=0x0040003c
Arithmetic overflow spim: (parser) syntax error on line 7 of file

/home/divyanshu/Documents/QtSpim_Codes_and_stuff/First Qtspim program.txt

.word 2,4,6,8,10 #array of integers

## please help me with how to initialise that array

## Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a number of errors.

1. the array should not have commas between elements
2. maybe a code past issue but the quotes on the string are not correct and should be "
3. $s1, $s1, $zero (3rd line of main) is not a valid instruction - you want to set s1 to 0.
4. start of loop: lw $t1, 0(#t0) is not valid, the # should $
5. addi $t0, $t0, $4: means t0 = t0 + a4 you want to add 4, so get rid of the $ to treat as a number.

Working for me:

```
   .data #Global Data here

N: .word 5 #loop count
X: .word 2 4 6 8 10 #array of integers
SUM: .word 0 #location of final sum
str : .asciiz "The sum of the array is ="

   .text
   .globl main #main defined globally
main: 
   lw $s0, N #Loop count N(initially must be zero) loaded in $s0
   la $t0,X #Address of X into t0
   move $s1, $zero

loop:
  lw $t1, 0($t0)
  add $s1,$s1,$t1
  addi $t0, $t0, 4
  addi $s0, $s0, -1

  bne $0, $s0, loop

  sw $s1, SUM

  li $v0, 10
  syscall
```

You still need to add your print statements etc if they are needed as part of the exercise.